# using PHPWord for create table in .doc file

Tags: php, ms-word, laravel-5.3, phpword

i want to export my table in word file(.doc). my project is in laravel and using PHPWord.structure is like in this image.
[image]
but there is a problem.created word document's design are not proper.i want design like in 1st image.so help me
[image]

Comment: You have to use docx template first and append the values to the files.[https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/samples/Sample_07_TemplateCloneRow.php]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Yes (PHP + HTML + CSS) (-;